# Jquery modal like tooltip plugin

Tags: jquery, tooltip, modal-dialog

This might be an easy question, but I am trying to come up with a solution for editing. For example a list of names is shown on a page and when the edit button beside each name is clicked, a dialog would popup showing all the details of that user, with a save and cancel button. I want the dialog to have a "tip" which points to the user being edited.

thanks,
RayraY

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean but there is a reasonably large choice of jQuery plugins for both modal dialogs and tooltips. They are easily discoverable via your favourite search engine, and are generally well documented and demo'd.

Comment: Thanks B, I did some research but could not find a tooltip like modal box. I have currently created a modal using the jquery ui plugins so I am going to try to custom it to include a pointer to the value that is been edited.

Comment: I expect the problem that you are having is that tooltips and modal dialogs are mutually exclusive, ie. plugins are wholly one or the other. It's hard to see what tooltip characteristics you require in your modal dialog. Reading your original post again, it appears that you appear to want a modal dialog, dynamically populated with existing text/values. This is a very common thing to do, especially in a so-called 'CRUD' (Create, Update, Delete) interface, which is what you appear to be trying to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a modal form, like this example taken from [jQuery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) site.

Once i did something like you need to do with a modal dialog: i had a lot of rows of a table and used modal dialogs to modify additional informations, each dialog of course contained a clear reference to the row i was editing

Comment: Thanks Nicola, yes I was looking into this, I will probably modify this to add some sort of pointer to the dialog. I was just wondering was there a tried and trusted method of using a dialog with a pointer to indicate which value was been edited.